# sharing data via cookie cross domain between 2 sites own by same company

Tags: cross-domain

I have following use case where one company owns both domain/site  X.com and Y.com

User visit X.com and then visit Y.com  or vice versa.
Each domain site  should know that it is same person who has visited other site.

means each domain need to give some anonymous id if it is not set for user (in browser memory such that it can share between domain.

I got understanding that mostly due to Cross origin/ITP browser policy 3rd party cookie may not be created or set in browser .

I m looking for solution if following approach work ?

any suggestion will be great  where both domain controlled by one company -can do server side changes.

**Approach 1:**

1. visit X.com/somepage.html ,x.com create unique id and set in x.com domain in browser memory as cookie.(normal client side cookie)
2. page has code to make request to Y.com with that cookie value. ( can be api call or image request with query string etc)
3. in response to request from x.com ,Y.com server read the value that is sent and in response in header set cookie in **Y.com domain** with **http only** (server side cookie)

**Approach 2:**

1. visit X.com/somepage.html ,x.com create unique id and set in x.com domain in browser memory as cookie.(normal client side cookie) here x.com also load hidden iframe with Y.com/blank.html

2)x.com page script do postmessage API send cookie value to Y.com/blank page in iframe.

3)Y.com/blank page in iframe receive the value and write in cookie in Y.com domain.

OR

3. Y.com/Blank page make API call to Y server and Y server write cookie as response to Y.com domain (as http only cookie or normal cookie)

somehow browser need to maintain same value for both domain so whenever it visit X or Y.com , it can represent as same person